# Avoid restarting docker when code is changed

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker for the first time, so it could be a stupid question for you. 
I configured: `dockerfile` and `docker-compose`.
Every time i change my code ( nodejs code ), I need to run the command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

If i want to see the changes, I want to know if there is a way to update my code without have to run that command every time.
Thanks.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
ENV NODE_PATH=/app/node_modules
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  node_api:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
```

Comment: Is your docker container looking at the local file system? If so, add file watching as part of the chain of scripts that run when you issue `npm start`. That way you can work on your files outside the container, with docker reloading appropriately.

Comment: Copy of your Dockerfile? Your mention of “build” suggests that you’re COPY’ing your source code into the image rather than bind mounting the source code directory from the host into the container, e.g. if you are copying the code into the container then you’re copying the code at the time the image was built essentially building an image with a static version of your code - unless you exec into the running container and edit the code there (not suggested as you may loose those changes) then you’re not modifying the running version of the code - just the code on your PC.

Comment: Your title is ambiguous. Avoid "need of manual" restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount the directory containing your source code in the container and use a tool such as [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/), which will watch files and restart the application on changes.

See  the article [Docker Tips : Development With Nodemon](https://medium.com/better-programming/docker-in-development-with-nodemon-d500366e74df) for details.

Comment: @afohr If this answer solves your problem, please click on the check mark at the left.